# Custom Authentication django

Tags: django, authentication, backend, custom-backend

I have  an app called `cAdmin` which for company users administration. And have Django superuser for create this company admins  , which is stored in `User Model` as well. I have a custom backend called `MyCustomAuthBackend` and it only check `CompanyAdmin model` credentials . But the problems is whenever i try to login using `User` model credentials  also allows . The reason that i foun is if the first backend fails it jumps over to next backend which is `ModelBackend`. How to stop when the first backend fails to jump to second back end in this specific app `cAdmin`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from .models import CompanyAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password,check_password

class MyCustomAuthBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = CompanyAdmin.objects.get(adminName=username)
            print(user.adminPassword,"      ",make_password(password))
            if check_password(password, user.adminPassword):
                print("worked password", user.adminPassword, password)
                #user.is_authenticated = True
                print(user,"printer duser")
                return user
            
        except CompanyAdmin.DoesNotExist:
            return None 
        return None
```

and the view is given below,

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control
from User.models import TicketDetails,Tickets,Category
from cAdmin.decorators import signin_required
#from cAdmin.backends import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True) 
def Login(request,id=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print("login view password")
        user=authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        print(user)
        if user:
            print(user)
            login(request,user)
            context = {'LoggedUser': user}
            return render(request,'cAdmin/adminDashboard.html',context) 
        else:
            return render(request, 'cAdmin/index.html',{'flag': 1})

    request.session.flush()
    return render(request, 'cAdmin/index.html',{})
```

and the order of Backend is given below,

`
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

```
 'cAdmin.backends.MyCustomAuthBackend',
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
```

]`

just used a middleware generated by chatGPT that did'nt worked

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class MyAppAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Check the current app and set the authentication backend accordingly
        if request.path.startswith('/cAdmin/'):
            print("Auth workeeeeeeeeeeeed")
            request.backend = 'cAdmin.backends.MyCustomAuthBackend'
        elif request.path.startswith('/'):

            request.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
            print("lhglhflghlfshdglhfdlh")
            

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

login in define your custom authentication backend

```
from .. import MyCustomAuthBackend
def Login(request,id=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print("login view password")
        if request.path.startswith('/cAdmin/'): 
            user=authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
            if user:
                login(request,user,,backend="django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend")
                context = {'LoggedUser': user}
                return render(request,'cAdmin/adminDashboard.html',context) 
        elif request.path.startswith('/'):
            
            email_auth = MyCustomAuthBackend()
            user=email_auth.authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
            if user:
                login(request,user,backend="cAdmin.backends.MyCustomAuthBackend")
                return render(request, 'cAdmin/index.html',{'flag': 1})

    request.session.flush()
    return render(request, 'cAdmin/index.html',{})
```

Comment: I have a small confusion over the first one, we use authenticate function first right? which function is using authentication backend whether it's authenticate or login? if authenticate uses backend then if a backend fails then it moves to another  as my code shows .And the second piece of code you provided is promising BTW . `login(request,user,backend="cAdmin.backends.MyCustomAuthBackend")` is this means when login it uses this backend or just for the session attribute??

Comment: updated answer.
you can move your code `if request.path.startswith('/cAdmin/')`  in Login function.

Comment: `login(request,user,backend="cAdmin.backends.MyCustomAuthBackend")` that means user login use this backend.